# In Dungeon Crawl, I've found two good weapons. What should be my weapon-use strategy, and why?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

[**Edit:** I've now also crossposted this to [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/dcss/comments/2h05ho/ive_found_two_good_weapons_what_should_be_my/) and also gotten a response there.]

I'm playing Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup 0.15.1. I'm a level 14 Gargoyle Fighter, strength 26, dexterity 14. I'm wearing +8 orange crystal plate armour I picked up off the floor in Lair.

I have two good weapons:

- A +0 lajatang. My Staves skill is 9.4.
- The +9 trident of the Candle {Speed, rPois rC+}. Gargoyles have inherent rPois. My effective Polearms skill is 4.4.

I don't have any slaying.

I've found both a +0 buckler and a +0 shield, but I can stash them if I end up choosing the lajatang. My Shields skill is 8.5.

Character dump:  http://pastebin.com/LPbps7XV

What should be my weapon-use strategy, and why?

Answer (score 4):

You found some amazing gear. The trident is far, far better than the lajatang -- speed is the best brand. Start skilling for Polearms at 100% until minimum delay is reached, 12 I think. Nothing else is more important for you. Forget trying to do spells, your armor is so heavy you won't be able to cast for a very long time, after you've got Armour up to 27 probably and have much more Int than you have now.

You are well on the way to becoming a real tank; AC 45 is monstrous. Forget about Shields, you don't need one. You can romp through the rest of Lair, being a bit more careful on the last level. Orc 1-3 should be no problem for you either, and 4 will just require a bit more caution. Same for Swamp and Spider's Nest.

You didn't pick a God! That's risky. You might want to pick Makhleb for the eventual summons to help you out or Kika perhaps. Trog's Brothers In Arms could also be a life saver for you in the Vaults.

https://crawl.develz.org/tavern/

is THE forum for Crawl. Post your dump in the "YASD! YAVP! and characters in progress too" and you get expert advice. I've won only a couple of times but I would be confident of at least a 3-rune victory with this guy.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please note that cerealjynx, [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/dcss/comments/2h05ho/ive_found_two_good_weapons_what_should_be_my/) on Reddit, disagrees with you. Who is right?

Comment: ask on the crawl site -- a +9 trident with speed will generate a lot more damage at minimum delay than an unenchanted lajatang. A demon trident may come along later that's even better.

Comment: Also consider the point of view of now versus the future - The +9 trident of speed is awesome right now.  The +0 unbranded latajang could be better in the future, once it is branded and has some bonuses.

Comment: It may not be clear to all that +9 means +9,+9. That's a bunch of damage. Since this build shouldn't be spending xp on spellcasting there should be plenty to get both Polearms and Staves to min delay and therefore be prepared for whatever comes next.